# How to make listings treat unknown languages as normal text

Tags: listings

When writing a code block for the plantuml language, I get the error `Package Listings Error: Couldn't load requested language.`. How can I ignore this error and just show the code block without code highlighting?

Note: As I'm exporting the latex from Emacs, the code always have a language (as I have code highlighting for it in Emacs).

Comment: just use listings to declare that language (but add no actual declarations)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can't I just set it to ignore the language if it's not found?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's just that I'm exporting the latex from Emacs and it exports with the language name, even if it's not supported in listings.

Comment: I still get the same error Couldn't load requested language. The code block shows, but I lose some format settings such as line numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `plantuml` to be an alias for an existing language eg the empty default language

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstalias{plantuml}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=plantuml]
a
bb
ccc
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]